# I'm confused why this won't print my text file

Tags: python

```
def readText():
    f = open("scores.txt", "r")

def showText():
    for line in f:
        w, x, y, z  = line.split()
        print(w, x, y, z)

readText()
showText()
```

Comment: `f` is not in the `showText()` scope, both functions to be fixed, or collapse the 2nd one into the first, no reason why there should be one for opening and one for reading.

Comment: @FishingCode My professor said we have to use at least 2 functions.

Comment: return f from readText and then pass it into showText. Be careful with variable name though

Comment: Your function names don't really match what they're doing.  The first function doesn't read the text.  It just opens the file.  The second function doesn't just show the text, but it reads it as well.  Perhaps you should change the first function to actually read the contents of the file, storing it in a list that you then pass to `showText`.  Don't forget to close the file after reading.

Comment: Reading from a file means pulling the contents of the file into your program.  Opening a file merely prepares it for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All good answers in this thread, the major issue you are encountering is with the scope.

```py
def readText():
  inputText = [] # empty list
  # open the file
  with open('scores.txt','r') as scores:
  # traverse through the file and add each score to the list
    for line in scores:
      inputText.append(line)
  return inputText # return the list

def showText():
  outputText = readText() # get the list from readText()
  # traverse the list and output each score
  for line in outputText:
    print(line)

showText()
```

My answer shows another way to accomplish your task if the scores are in a file separated by new lines- though it is not the best solution due to 'redundant variables', with Python there are many ways to accomplish a task. Good luck with the rest of your education!

Edit: another solution if the scores are in one line separated by a comma:

```py
def readText():
    with open('scores.txt','r') as scores:
        for line in scores:
            inputText = line.split(',')
    return inputText
def showText():
  outputText = readText()
  for line in outputText:
    print(line)

showText()
```

Comment: the variable `text` is used in the first function, change the variable called in the second function for better clarity :-)

Comment: This is better, but you introduce slightly different handling of the line. It would probably be perfect if you reverted to the `split` approach.

Answer (score 3):

The variable f is not in scope for the show text function.

```
def openText():
    f = open("scores.txt", "r")
    return f # Return the value of the file

def readAndShowText(f): # by passing the value in, you now have access to the variable
    for line in f:
        w, x, y, z  = line.split()
        print(w, x, y, z)

file = openText() # set the return value
readAndShowText(file) # pass the value into the showtext
file.close() # make sure you close it
```

You'll notice I've also changed the function names to better reflect what they do, as suggested in a comment.

Comment: @Tom, I think I fixed all those, you may want to have a look to see if I've missed anything, or introduced other problems.

Answer (score 1):

Straight forward answer:

```
filename = input("Enter path to file:")
def getLines(filename):
   f = open(filename, "r")
   for line in f.readlines():
       w,x,y,z = line.split()
       print(w,x,y,z)
   f.close()
```

Two function approach:

```
def readFile():
   f = open("/path/to/filename/scores.txt", "r")
   return f

def getLines(f):
    for line in f:
      w, x, y, z  = line.split()
      print(w, x, y, z)
    f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":

   getMyLines = readFile()
   getLines(getMyLines)
```

Comment: These function names don't match what the functions do. It may fix the main bug, but it ignores the other major problems with the code. You also forgot to close the file after reading from it.